# sorcery with mongoid throwing transaction undefined

Tags: mongoid, sorcery

On following line from controller

```
@user = create_from(provider)
```

Getting exception

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `transaction' for User:Class>
```

Here is the first line of exception backtrace

```
"/Users/Gull/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview2/gems/sorcery-0.8.4/lib/sorcery/controller/submodules/external.rb:173:in `create_from'"
```

This make sense that transaction are not supported by mongo, but is the configuration part that is invoking the transaction part of sorcery ?

Answer (score 0):

adding following line in the model file ... make it working

```
  include Sorcery::Model::Adapters::Mongoid
```